# Black background on VideoView Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a videoview which displays horizontal. The video that I am showing is vertical. I have an empty space in my ViewView outside my real video. The Video is showing like this.

[image]

The red rectangle is my video, but my VideoView covers all screen's width. 
I want to change the gray color to a black color, but this is not working. I set black color and I'm still having gray. This only happens with black, if I try with green, yellow or red, the color is replaced perfectly.

This is how I'm using my view.

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/videoView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/FileNotFound"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Video not found"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

In my class, I'm setting this attributes

```
 videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
 videoView.requestFocus();
 videoView.start();
 videoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Is there any way to set black background?

Answer (score 0):

#### This method work for me

```
VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);

videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```